# How to merge two tables while preserving all values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am relatively new to python and I am wondering how I can merge these two tables and preserve both their values?

Consider these two tables:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 3], [2, 4],[2.5,1],[5,6],[7,8]], columns=['A', 'B'])

A     B
1     3
2     4
2.5   1
5     6
7     8

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8]], columns=['A'])

A
1
2
...
8
```

I want to obtain the following result:

```
A     B
1     3
2     4
2.5   1
3     NaN
4     NaN
5     6
6     NaN
7     8
8     NaN
```

You can see that column A includes all values from both the first and second dataframe in an ordered manner.
I have attempted:

```
pd.merge(df,df2,how='outer')
pd.merge(df,df2,how='right')
```

But the former does not result in an ordered dataframe and the latter does not include rows that are unique to df.

Comment: you can sort your values after the merge. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us do `concat` then `drop_duplicates`

```
out = pd.concat([df2,df]).drop_duplicates('A',keep='last').sort_values('A')
Out[96]: 
     A    B
0  1.0  3.0
1  2.0  4.0
2  2.5  1.0
2  3.0  NaN
3  4.0  NaN
3  5.0  6.0
5  6.0  NaN
4  7.0  8.0
7  8.0  NaN
```